# ExtJS TreeStore is empty if I load store by manually

Tags: extjs

Model

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.model.mail.MailFoldersModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.String'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'idParent'
        },
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'text'
        }
    ]
});
```

My TreeStore

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.store.mail.MailFoldersStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

  requires: [
    'MyDesktop.model.mail.MailFoldersModel'
  ],

  constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
      storeId: 'MailFoldersStore',
      model: 'MyDesktop.model.mail.MailFoldersModel',
      autoLoad: true,
      proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://url/mail/folders',
        reader: {
          type: 'json',
          rootProperty: 'items',
          successProperty: 'success'
        }
      },
      root: {
        text: 'root',
        iconCls: 'mail-folders-owner'
      }
    }, cfg)]);
  }
});
```

Store is autoloaded, all works correctly, store contains 11 records.

```
var MailFoldersStore = Ext.create('MyDesktop.store.mail.MailFoldersStore', {
  storeId: 'MailFoldersStore'
});
```

If I set autoLoad to false and trying to load by manually - store is empty, 0 records.

```
var MailFoldersStore = Ext.create('MyDesktop.store.mail.MailFoldersStore', {
  storeId: 'MailFoldersStore'
});
MailFoldersStore.load({
  callback : function(records, operation, success) {
    console.log(records);
  }
});
```

What can be a reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also has same problem. I am using Extjs 5.1. After googling I found one complex solution which needs us to modify the framework.

See the below link if it can help you.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?154823-listeners-quot-exception-quot-in-proxy.ajax-on-TreeStore-do-not-work

Comment: Thanks! I will check your solution some later. Thank you for your answer